# AWS account Billing for Alexa Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have just created AWS and amazon developer account for creating skills, but Amazon saved billing information. Will I be charged for creating Lambda functions to map with my custom skills, I will just be using my account for creating simple skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with simple skills without a large number of users you don't have to worry because AWS gives you some free Lambda requests per month.

But if you only have to create simple skills, you can use [Alexa Hosted Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html) without using an AWS account

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be charged for creating skills and as you have created an account recently for one year you will be in the free tier which offers one million AWS Lambda requests per month which I think is more than enough for testing/creating sample skills. So, the final verdict is that you don't need to worry about any billing unless and until you have exceeded the free tier limits(which is almost not possible). You can get info about AWS Free Tier [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc).